# Websocket connection is failed [env: django channel, gunicorn, uvicorn, nginx, postgre and redis over https(wss)}

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, channel, uvicorn

I have deployed my app on digitalOcean using this tutorial [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-asgi-django-app-with-postgres-nginx-and-uvicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04) ,https and all pages rendering properly and django working fine, The issue right now is websocket connection is failed, the error messages I got are from console web page says:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://mysitedomain/ws/chat/2_3/'
> failed:

Other error message from gunicorn server shows 404 not found page:

> "GET /ws/chat/2_3/ HTTP/1.0" 404

Regardless what wss configuration I add it to nginx configuration file; connection is failed!!.. below is mysite configuration file under 'etc/nginx/sites_available' folder in linux for your reference ( I have removed all wss configuration blocks):

***please note I already have installed uvicorn[standard] version but didn't help!!***

```
 server {
    listen 80;
    server_name IP domain name;

  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/user/DjangoProject;
   }
  location / {
    include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
    
}
```